# Can't retrive nested data for various push keys in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app where I want to get nested data for different users. It's like a news feed. I want to show only the value of "status" for each user. But I don't know how to do it using Query. I don't know how to bypass the randomly generated unique push keys. This is how my firebase database looks like:
[My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNr1A.jpg)

I tried something like this in my java code in android studio:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNOIk.jpg)

But it's not working. :(

Comment: Add your code here not in image...

Comment: can you explain what you want exactly?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?